# С помощью чего, какого плагина это реализовать?

Tags: jquery, html, javascript, css

http://s020.radikal.ru/i714/1403/85/75c29c3e6abb.png

Мне нужно чтобы ползунок двигался, и цена менялась разумеется. Посоветуйте плагин, чтоб еще стили можно было бы поменять в нем, чтоб было возможно его сделать таким, как на фото. Срочно нужна помощь. Заранее благодарю

Comment: на всякий случай напомню, что история правок сохраняется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ползунок_UI

http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range

http://egorkhmelev.github.io/jslider/

http://acblog.ru/range-sliders/

Comment: Вам на фриланс! Создайте там задание и Вам его сделают!